# Ionic 3 Keyboard Transition Issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3.8.0, and I am having an issue with the keyboard transition animation.

When the keyboard slides up, there is a white/black background where the keyboard will go.

When the keyboard slides down, there is a white/black background where the keyboard was.

This issue appears to affect the Ionic DevApp as well. In this case, there is a white background.

Here is a screenshot:

Ionic DevApp Keyboard Transition Issue:

[image]

Is there a way to make the keyboard slide without the white/black background behind it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an image?

Comment: I think that issue come from your phone. Try with other phone and show the result.

Comment: I see the same thing with both an iPhone and an Android phone.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?